# Symfony route without controller

Tags: symfony

I have to work on a Symfony project that I never met before. There is a route that I'd like to figure out what script generates the result. Normally int the routing.yml the the `_controller` in the `defaults` tells this, but this route does not have any controller associated with:

```
vendorname_admin_generate_external_site_admin:
    path: /admin/
    host: "{current}.%vendorname_academic_base_host%"
    defaults: {current: %vendorname_academic_base_subdomain%}
```

The two parameters are:

```
vendorname_academic_base_host: vendordomain.com
vendorname_academic_base_subdomain: developmentserver-vpn
```

Could you help me to understand what does this route definition do?

Comment: I think `current`is your locale ....so host would be `en.vendordomain.com` as an example.

Comment: Did you look at info generated by the profiler?. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the fact it is defining a specific host (ie, a domain name) as part of the route, makes me think that it's just an alias to an external website, that isn't actually in the same codebase.  -- Also the fact its called '*external_site_admin*'.

I've just added a similar route with a specific host, mine is still in the same codebase, but under a specific, shorter URL, but I defined my route as a template that I can use to setup as an alias.